# Как получать из контактов email с номером телефона одновременно?

Tags: java, android

Вот мой код который получает номера телефонов и имена одного и того же контакта

```
public void test111(View view) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                if (pCur != null) {
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        Logger.log(MainActivity.class, "!!!!!!!!! Name : " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Logger.ERROR);
                    }
                }
                if (pCur != null) {
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том, что если мне нужно получить майл адрес если он есть у этого контакта, то мне нужно создавать новый курсор,

```
Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);
```

а он насколько я понимаю соберет все доступные майл адреса, но для меня они будут не упорядочены...

Как сделать так чтоб метод возвращал инфу по каждому контакту если есть майл то `имя, номер, майл` если нет то `имя, номер, null`?

Или подскажите как это правильно делается?

Или может можно как то получать `vCard` карточку абонента со всеми его данными... Ведь это как то работает когда допустим по смс выбираем карточку нужного человека и отправляем ее...

Можно как то получать программно такую карточку по каждому абоненту в телефонной книге и получать по этой карте всю инфу по конкретному юзеру?

Comment: > но для меня они будут не упорядочены...

а в каком виде Вы их хотите? или достаточно одного - основного e-mail?

Comment: какая версия андроид ?

Comment: @gecube мне нужно получать все строки с карточки абонента (Имя, Фамилия, номер, фото, майл адресс и т.д) по конкретному абоненту... В моем примере я могу получить отдельно имя и номер, для того, чтоб получить майл мне нужно создать новый курсор, но следовательно я не смогу привязать полученый майл к конкретному абоненту, так как не буду знать чей он...

Comment: @SeniorAutomator 21

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko не хочешь юзать ContactsContract.Profile или AccountManager ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator там по моему в вопросе в конце я написал, что мне без разницы как получать данные, главное, чтоб они были все и по конкретному абоненту... Твои реализации для этого подходят? Я просто не знаком с ними...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге у меня получилось такое

```
    private void readContacts() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        int e = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {

                Cursor pCur = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                Cursor eCur = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                String phoneNo = null;
                if (pCur != null) {
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    }
                }

                String email = null;
                if (eCur != null) {
                    if (eCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        email = eCur.getString(eCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    }
                }

                    e++;
                    Logger.log(MainActivity.class, e + ")  Name : " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo + " , email : " + email, Logger.ERROR);


                if (pCur != null) {
                    pCur.close();
                }

                if (eCur != null) {
                    eCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: зачем логировать как ошибку, если email != null ?

Comment: Разнесите циклы по `pCur` и `eCur` – непонятно, почему они вложены друг в друга. В остальном – примерно так, да.

Comment: @eigenein не до конца понял... Но тогда мне прийдется еще один `while` сделать, а это будет означать что сначала будет выполняться один цикл а за ним другой и значения которые они будут возвращать уже не будут относиться к одному обьекту... Я наверное не так вас понял... Как правильно?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Они будут относиться к одному и тому же контакту, почему нет?

Comment: @eigenein да, точно... Все работает и дубли убрались... Спасибо! Нужно мне почитать как работать с базами.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko помогли хоть? выбери ответ правильный какой нить

Answer (score 1):

Ваш курсор

```
Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { id }, null);
```

выберет адреса только одного контакта, точно так же, как вы выбрали номера телефонов. Вы ведь задали условие `CONTACT_ID = ?`. И вы точно знаете, к какому контакту они относятся, делая это внутри цикла по контактам.

Итого, для каждого контакта вы имеете список телефонов и список email адресов. Затем группируете как вам угодно. В простейшем случае – выбираете первый телефон из курсора с телефонами и первый адрес из курсора с адресами (при отсутствии выбираете `null`). Все.

Comment: Я опубликовал ответ как это вышло у меня, можете пожалуйста глянуть, норм или нет?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public HashMap<String, String> getNameEmailDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> names = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) {
                    //to get the contact names
                    String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.e("Name :", name);
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    Log.e("Email", email);
                    String number = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.e("number", number);
                    if(email!=null){
                        names.put(name, email);
                    }
                }
                cur1.close();
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
```

Comment: В вашем случае курсор будет всегда возвращать емаил и вместо номера телефона тоже емаил, так как в вашем курсоре указано `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email`  ...

Comment: Я опубликовал ответ как это вышло у меня, можете пожалуйста глянуть, норм или нет?

Comment: `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI` – по этому адресу же будут лежать только адреса, не телефоны?